# Fresh install of ubuntu zesty server from dvd not upgradeable

Tags: server, apt, upgrade, updates, official-repositories

After downloading the amd64 zesty server iso and burning it to dvd I did a fresh install with **nothing but the basic packages**. I did not check any of the optional 'boxes' during the install. There are no other operating systems on the drive.

When I try to do

> sudo apt update && sudo apt upgrade

the attempt fails with

> E: The repository 'http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu zesty Release' does no longer have a Release file.
>
> N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default

The same error message is also given for **zesty-security** and **zesty-updates**.

This seems to be strange behavior for such a basic installation.

One would presume that us.archive.ubuntu.com would be secure if any archive is secure.

***Is there a way to force the update and upgrade?***

**Additional information:** If I simply do

> sudo apt upgrade

I get multiple

> Could not resolve 'us.archive.ubuntu.com'

messages.

I tried the suggestion that it might be an IVP6 issue and did a suggested edit to /etc/gai.conf but that had no effect

Comment: The `couldn't resolve` is actually interesting. Can you open this link in a browser, or does it fails too? http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/zesty/

Comment: I did not install a GUI on the server. I have no trouble accessing it from my current desktop box, only the server.

Comment: Alright then, can you do `ping us.archive.ubuntu.com` from the server?

Comment: No, I cannot ping it.

Comment: Then your question comes down not to getting updates, but to configuring network. Can you do e.g. `ping 8.8.8.8`? Can you paste into the post output of `ip addr`?

Comment: Had no trouble pinging Google's DNS server. And 'ip addr' show that I do have a local ip address on enp2s0. But I cannot copy and paste since another issue is that redirection using 'command > output.txt' or ' command | tee output.txt' are not working either.

Comment: Okay, how did you configure the network? I.e. did you use network manager, or /etc/network/interfaces?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/61186/discussion-between-john-wayland-bales-and-hi-angel).

Answer (score 2):

I am posting this in case the solution to my issue should prove helpful to someone else with the same issue who might happen upon this question here.

Thanks to the extensive assistance given to me by @HiAngel in chat we were able to focus this to a networking issue.

During install of Ubuntu zesty server from DVD the installer did not detect an internet connection so was unable to update and upgrade during installation. After installation I tried to upgrade using

> sudo apt update && sudo apt upgrade

but could not connect to us.archive.ubuntu.com

The solution was to manually edit using 'sudo vim' (since I did not install a GUI) the /etc/network/interfaces file.

The file was lacking a line for 'gateway' and for 'dns-nameserver'

I after locating the IP adresses for my provider's nameservers, I added the line

> dns-nameservers (I inserted a list here)

Using the output from

> ip route | grep default

I added a line

> gateway (I added IP address followed for good measure the strings produced by the ip route default)

I rebooted and then had no problem with update & upgrade.